# jQuery - Different function on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a curtain Opening & Closing effect.  But for some reason I can't make my curtains close once they're opened.

**Here's what I have so far:** http://jsfiddle.net/ssc3z1tf/

I've tried quite a few different ways, adding and removing classes, toggling classes and here I've used rels.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             $('.curtain').click(function(){
                if ($('.curtain').attr('rel', 'open')){
                        $('.curtainLeft').animate({"left":"-400px"}, "slow");
                        $('.curtainRight').animate({"right":"-400px"}, "slow");
                        $('.curtain').attr('rel', 'closed');

                    } else if ($('.curtain').attr('rel', 'closed')){

                        $('.curtainLeft').animate({"left":"-0px"}, "slow");
                        $('.curtainRight').animate({"right":"-0px"}, "slow");
                        $('.curtain').attr('rel', 'open');
                    }
            });
        });
```

Any help would be great!  I'm lost!  Thanks!!

Comment: In your `if` you want to check if `rel` is  `open` but you set it to `open`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
if ($('.curtain').attr('rel', 'open')){
```

to

```
if ($('.curtain').attr('rel') == 'open') {
```

And do the same for the second if statement. The `.attr(name, value)` will always set the attribute to the specified value, whereas `.attr(name)` will simply return the value

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssc3z1tf/1/)

Comment: Perfect!  Still getting to grips with jQuery!  Thanks for your help! :)