# Can't uncheck in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox set up that is supposed to add and remove layers with leaflet. Right now I can't get the checkbox to uncheck.

HTML:

```
<form action="">
    <input type="checkbox" id="pointCheck" value="true">Points &nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" id="lineCheck">Lines &nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" id="polygonCheck">Polygons &nbsp;
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
    if($("#pointCheck").prop('checked', true)){
        $.getJSON("../data/point.json").done(function(data){
            addPoints(data);
            console.log("hello");
        });
    }
    else if($("#pointCheck").prop('checked', false)){
        console.log("remove");
    }
})
```

Comment: `$("#pointCheck").prop('checked', booleanValue)` sets the property value. `$("#pointCheck").prop('checked')` gets the property value.

Comment: `.prop(property, value)` is the setter. You're setting its value to true. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491274/jquery-different-function-on-second-click/25491316

Comment: You're using the setter of `prop` in the condition. Instead use `prop('checked')` or `is(':checked');`

Answer (score 5):

again I just answered seem of that question 1hour ago to check

```
if($("#pointCheck").is(':checked')){
    alert('button checked');
}else{
   alert('button unchecked');
}
```

You can use the next code to set the attr checked (to make the #pointCheck checked and false to unchecked)  and for your information you can use prop also with selected and disabled .. same way ..

```
$("#pointCheck").prop('checked', true)
```

And as @TheGrandPackard mentioned in comment [Manual Reference](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: @TheGrandPackard I updated my answer with your link .. if this link for me .. I should say I know all of that .. but when I coming to answer any question I answer it with the code I tested before and worked for me on my projects and be sure its working .. with javascript we can find more and more of solutions for the same case .. I appreciate your comment and your reference link .. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: I included the reference in case anyone wanted to read up on it more, and I myself used it to double check your work before upvoting your answer. Good answer!

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can use `$("#pointCheck").prop('checked') == true`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":checkbox").click(function(){
        console.log($("#pointCheck").prop('checked'));
        if($("#pointCheck").prop('checked') == true){
            $.getJSON("../data/point.json").done(function(data){
                addPoints(data);
                console.log("hello");
            });
        }
        else if($("#pointCheck").prop('checked') == false){
            console.log("remove");
        }
    });
});
```